# beautifulsoup tags with embedded id="x" python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have xml that I am trying to extract from that looks like this:

```
 <transactionCoding>
            <transactionFormType>4</transactionFormType>
            <transactionCode>S</transactionCode>
            <equitySwapInvolved>0</equitySwapInvolved>
            <footnoteId id="F1"/>
```

I can get all of the values of each tag except the footnoteid, whhich comes back as none. I have tried every function of footnoteid.string, gettext getattr,etc but nothing works. I need to get the value F1 out of the tag, but I can't figure out how

here's the code:

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def parse_xml_string(fls):
        temp = fls.find_next("value")
        t = temp.text
        print (t)
        return (t)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    nonderivtxn = soup.find_all("nonderivativetransaction")

    nd =  [[] for _ in range(len(nonderivtxn))]


    for index in range(len(nonderivtxn)):
            coding = nonderivtxn[index]. find("transactioncoding")
            tformtype = coding.transactionformtype.text
            tcode = coding.transactioncode.text
            swapinvolved = coding.equityswapinvolved.text
            footnote= coding.footnoteid.gettext()
            print (tcode,swapinvolved,footnote.content,tformtype)
```

Comment: can you share the code that is runable ? atleast add the webpage you want to access

Comment: What do you mean by "values", the text? `<footnoteId id="F1"/>` is an empty element. It has no text or child elements.

Comment: Did you want `coding.footnoteId["id"]` ? (note also the caps for footnoteId)

Comment: The xml snippet comes from a form 4 via the SEC EDGAR system. By values, I mean the data between the xml tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you have xml that looks like this:

```
<footnotes><footnote id="F1">See Exhibit 99.1 for text of footnote (1).</footnote><footnote id="F2">See Exhibit 99.1 for text of footnote (2).</footnote><footnote id="F3">See Exhibit 99.1 for text of footnote (3).</footnote><footnote id="F4">See Exhibit 99.1 for text of footnote (4).</footnote><footnote id="F5">See Exhibit 99.1 for text of footnote (5).</footnote></footnotes>
```

The footnotes were loaded into an array with the find_all function.
You can access the values with this code:

```
def get_footnote_list(id,footnote_array):
fl = []

for i in range(len(id)):
    for j in range(len(footnote_array)):
        if id[i] == footnote_array[j].get("id"):
            fl.append(footnote_array[j].decode_contents())

return (fl)
```